# c# compare input to mysql value

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

I wanted to create a function on which a user can guess the value from a MySQL database. label2 is randomly generated by other codes, so the user will have to guess the partner value of the label2 by inputting texbox1. I try to use the usual login function for the code

```
 s = "SELECT val2 FROM data_reader.db WHERE val1='" + this.label2.Text + "'and image='" + this.textBox1.Text + "';";
                int count = 0;

            while (mdr.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("correct");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("wrong");
            }
```

problem with this code is it always return wrong even when the value are correct. is there any missing algorithm or maybe my code is not suitable for this purpose?

Comment: Maybe use `if (count >= 1)` instead of `==`? Why are you counting if you expect there to be only one answer? Or can there be multiple rows with the same `val1` and `image` values?

Comment: Wjhat's the relationship between `s` and `mdr.Read()`?

Comment: Please don't concatenate strings to form an SQL query. You are extremely open to SQL Injection attacks with this approach. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 2):

You forgot insert a space character between the `label2.Text` value and the `AND` junction.

```
s = "SELECT val2 FROM data_reader.db WHERE val1='" + this.label2.Text 
    + "' AND image='" + this.textBox1.Text + "';";
```

Comment: hi, i think there something wrong with my mysql query, I have a database which is data_reader.db, I wanted to find the value of image(char not filepath). val1 have been randomly generated so i have to guess the image value...any idea? –

Answer (score 0):

Ok i'll help you with something else here

First: Lesson i learned here, never use " + ", you should use AddWithValue on the query parameters, something like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT val2 FROM data_reader.db WHERE val1 = @value1 and image=@image";
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", this.label2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", this.textBox1.Text);
```

It is easier to understand and more secure.

Second: You just need to use

```
if (mdr.Read())
{
    MessageBox.Show("Correct!");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Wrong!");
}
```

Comment: hi, i think there something wrong with my mysql query, I have a database which is data_reader.db, I wanted to find the value of image(char not filepath). val1 have been randomly generated so i have to guess the image value...any idea?